# MS Access taking too long to save form

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form in MS Access that takes too long to save. It's a multiuser environment and the time to save the form increases. There was some improvement witnessed when I moved all record/rowsources to be set on runtime. However, when there are multiple users access the form, there's lag of 2-3 minutes or more. There are about 15-20 users accessing the application.
There are about 40 to 45 textboxes/comboboxes on the form. The backend is SQL Server.
I have also tried rebuilding one of the indexes which was fragmented about 58%.
What can I do improve the performance of the app?

Comment: Is the form bound to one or more recordsets? Have you tried using pass through queries in Access or views set up in SQL server to give you the recordset that you need?

Comment: Yes a lot of fields are bound. I see that the table gets locked in SQL with type LCK_M_IX. I haven't tried pass through queries. I'll see if I can create a view.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data source for the form so that it isn't bound to the tables in SQL Server. Populate the form using Pass Through queries or set up a view in the SQL Server database.

Comment: Are pass through queries good for update of tables? I hear they work well on select statements.

Comment: The difference between a pass through query and a standard one is simply that it's sent straight through to the server database. You can do any type of operation with a pass through including updates.

Comment: Wouldn't Access save all the bound controls automatically, which will not do away with the delay?

Comment: You need to control the display and editing of the data in order to improve the performance. Binding the controls gives you no scope to manage this. Have you tried unbinding the controls?

Comment: So I'm looking for latebinding of controls? No, I haven't tried that because there are about 45 of them. There's no subform here, and the data needs to be displayed, too. I have tried unbinding only for comboboxes.